# “Update dependencies” option missing in "Update Maven Project" for new java-mvn project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven, maven-dependency

I have a Java-Maven project imported in Eclipse. When I right click on the Project > Maven > Update Project, I see "Update Dependencies" option greyed out(not accessible) but "Force Update of Snapshots/Release" option accessible.

Eclipse version - "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers, Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)"

Mac operation system is used.

I have tried "mvn eclipse:eclipse" on the project via cmd, "mvn clean install" and all dependencies are showing fine.

I want to understand why is "Update Dependencies" greyed out and what can be done to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

On this thread on the m2e mailing list, someone asked "*What does the 'greyed out' update dependencies symbolize?*" And the developer answered that "*this action always updates dependencies and there is no way to disable that.* (https://www.eclipse.org/lists/m2e-dev/msg00904.html).

So, there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: The developer's answer that there is no way to disable the 'greyed out' Update dependencies. Does it mean, we can't enable it or we don't need to?

Comment: The option is always checked, but the input interaction is disabled. That means you can't uncheck it. It will always update the eclipse project classpath libs based on pom.xml your dependencies.